# How to remove the inscription in Navigation Bar and leave arrow

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I need to remove the inscription next to the arrow. Do as shown in the screenshot

[This is my photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exBps.png)

[That's how i need to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exBps.png)

Comment: i think you post same images in both links.

Answer (score 0):

In the UIViewController subclass where you want a back arrow without the text, do the following in `viewDidLoad`

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Comment: I need one arrow left, as shown here : https://drive.google.com/open?id=10yRZz-gaMyvwLNsQon9RgyXYTY3n59dJ

Comment: And I have the text remained: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JdkVtnLq15QStdYE3fchvaPZ-EzqanMP